# How to format dates in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to format my date with a `Now` function. I want to declare the month and date but not the year.

Ex: `=DATE(TEXT(NOW(),"yyyy"),1,1)` = 01/01/2019. What would be the VBA equivalent?

Comment: You could have used the `YEAR` function instead of `TEXT`. That would make the formula equivalent even more similar to the VBA answer proposed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
DateSerial(Year(Now), 1, 1)
```

If you need to format:

```
Format$(DateSerial(Year(Now), 1, 1), "mm/dd/yyyy") ' or whatever date format
```